# How long does it take for Cloudflare to start resolving a site?

Tags: wordpress, cloudflare

I tried to switch over the Cloudflare on a live site that is expected to get a ton of traffic. Unfortunately, after I switched the DNS servers over, I got 523 errors for about 20 minutes before I gave up on it. Traceroute and ping reported "unknown host" during this time. I double-checked the DNS servers cloudflare had me switch to and they were correct. I have set this up on a WordPress site using the official cloudlflare plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/cloudflare

Is it normal for a site to go down for so long when switching over? I've never used Cloudflare before.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not normal for a site to go down.  The DNS change will spread but until then, unless you changed other things about your site, people should still be redirected to your origin from your old DNS.

A 523 error suggests a problem with your origin.  I'd suggest contacting cloudflare.  It's actually possible the PLUGIN is the issue, as cloudflare's default behavior generally fine for a static wordpress site.